# No access to router via eth lan port, only accessible over wifi

Tags: networking, linux-networking, router, wifi, busybox

Router is an old Intento FG101R2 connected via fiber and has 4 Lan ports.

After fiddling around and numerous factory resets I no longer have access to router and internet via any of the Eth ports on the router, but I can access and have internet connection over wireless.

Tried with multiple machines, cables, ports, by manually adding and automatically obtaining IP settings on client machine. I also tried to configure second IP Address and Subnet Mask for LAN interface via Router's web interface but still didn't get IP settings from DHCP and manually setting IP and gateway on client machine had no success.

Following outputs are taken right after factory reset, while still having access to router and internet connection over Wireless.

**Current routes are as follow (ISP's gateway X-d out):**

```
> route show

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
XXX.XXX.XX.X    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0.6.2
default         XXX.XXX.XX.X    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0.6.2
```

**Bridge, created automatically after factory reset:**

```
> brctl show

bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.000000000002       no              wl0
                                                        wl0.1
                                                        wl0.2
                                                        wl0.3
```

**ifconfig (public IP X-d out, didn't edit any of the HWaddr):**

```
> ifconfig

br0             Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:02
                inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
                UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
                RX packets:33494 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                TX packets:32654 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
                RX bytes:2369860 (2.2 MiB)  TX bytes:40415361 (38.5 MiB)

eth0            Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
                UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
                RX packets:74309 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                TX packets:30848 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
                RX bytes:43378501 (41.3 MiB)  TX bytes:2762411 (2.6 MiB)
                Interrupt:25 Base address:0x5120

eth0.5          Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
                UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
                RX packets:2098 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                TX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
                RX bytes:623538 (608.9 KiB)  TX bytes:68 (68.0 B)


eth0.6          Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
                UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
                RX packets:72211 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                TX packets:30843 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
                RX bytes:42754963 (40.7 MiB)  TX bytes:2762071 (2.6 MiB)


eth0.6.2        Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:03
                inet addr:XXX.XXX.XX.XXX  Bcast:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  Mask:255.255.255.0
                UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
                RX packets:72203 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                TX packets:30843 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
                RX bytes:41454581 (39.5 MiB)  TX bytes:2599793 (2.4 MiB)

lo              Link encap:Local Loopback
                inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
                UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
                RX packets:80 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                TX packets:80 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
                RX bytes:3656 (3.5 KiB)  TX bytes:3656 (3.5 KiB)

wl0             Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:02
                UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
                RX packets:32959 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:21980
                TX packets:32847 errors:3 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
                RX bytes:2755587 (2.6 MiB)  TX bytes:40960743 (39.0 MiB)
                Interrupt:39
```

**iptables:**

```
> iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpts:10000:10008
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:5060
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:5060
ACCEPT     udp  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere            udp dpt:30006
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:30005

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             239.255.255.250
```

**Dhcp server config(udhcpd):**

```
> dhcpserver show

start 192.168.1.2
end 192.168.1.254
interface br0
decline_file /var/udhcpd.decline
option lease 86400
option min_lease 30
option subnet 255.255.255.0
option router 192.168.1.1
option dns 192.168.1.1
option dns 192.168.1.1
option domain Home
```

**System log after factory reset and reboot:** 
https://pastebin.com/TZJUN5Ji (X-d out my IP, ISP's gateway and DNS server. Weird thing is that all my Mac's are 0-d out and also not sure why the ip 128.9.0.107 is there because it's not related to my ISP or me at all)

Let me know if there is anything else I can add and any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated!

--

**EDIT:**
 Tried adding eth0.5 to bridge br0, got an error `can't add eth0.5 to bridge br0: Cannot assign requested address` .
Brought the interface down and assigned random MAC address to eth0.5 and after that I was able to add eth0.5 to br0.

**Got an IP automatically via one of the ETH ports!** Was able to connect to router via Web interface but at the same time can't connect SSH/Telnet via neither, Wireless or Ethernet.

Found that DNS servers got put to 192.168.1.1 so I changed those to Google public ones via Web interface. After a bit of waiting I have internet access via both Wireless and Ethernet.

**EDIT:**
Looked around the web interface and double checked Access-control rules and checkboxes seem correct but still no SSH/Telnet access.

Tried adding other Lan ports to that bridge but that seems to break things and after that I couldn't ping ISP's gateway, so I did a factory reset and sticked to adding just eth0.5 to br0.

**EDIT:**
figuring this out step by step, I found that other ETH Lan ports(eth0.2, eth0.3, eth0.4) weren't marked as up so I did the same thing, assigned random Mac, added to bridge and marked them up. What made it break before was that I added eth0.6 to bridge which is used for WAN on eth0.6.2. Now all the LAN ports work, have access to internet and router via both Wireless and ETH. Also now have access to SSH/Telnet over ETH, which didn't seem to work right after adding to bridge.

--

**The issue** is that after rebooting the router those changes seem to revert, ETH interfaces are removed from the bridge and everything is back to where I started.

If anyone has an idea how I could make so that those changes don't revert back I will be very thankful.

Comment: This router is over 10 years old and is many years obsolete, not to mention it has unfixed security vulnerabilities. In your case it sounds like it's possible the internal flash is failing, which is something I would expect from a device that old. It's best to replace it with something currently supported, even if you weren't having problems with it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I must agree with you, this router is way past it's time and I'm currently looking into replacing it.